# Is the Hausdorff measure absolutely continuous with respect to the lebesgue measure? $H^{d-1} \ll \lambda^d$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, radon-nikodym, hausdorff-measure

I'm sure this is just basic theory but I can't find this ANYWHERE. Is it true that
$$
H^{d-1} \ll \lambda^d
$$
where $H^{d-1}$ is the $(d-1)$-dimensinal Hausdorff measure and $\lambda^d$ is the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

- If this is true, does the Radon-Nykodym derivative $\frac{d H^{d-1}}{d \lambda^d}$ exist? And what can we say about it?
- If this is not true, is there a similar relation? For instance with different dimensions.

Comment: What can you say about $H^{d-1}(E)$ And $\lambda^{d}(E)$ for a $(d-1)$-dimensional unit cube $E=[0,1]^{d-1}\times\{0\}$?

Comment: Mm I recon that $\lambda^d(\underbrace{[0, 1] \times \cdots \times [0,1]}_{d-1}) = 1$

Comment: Well, we have $\lambda^{d}(E)=\bigl[\lambda^{1}([0,1])\bigr]^{d-1} \cdot \lambda^{1}(\{0\}) = 0$. Intuitively, lower-dimensional objects are 'too small' to have non-trivial $d$-dimensional contents.

Comment: Oh wow... I am very much a novice to measure theory so do you mind writing down some of the details?

Comment: Think of this example: A line segment $L=[0, 1]\times\{0\}$ in the plane has zero area but unit length. This is the same as telling that $\lambda^{2}(L)=0$ but $H^{1}(L)=1$ for the $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $H^{1}$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @SangchulLee That makes so much sense! So basically on a plane the line is infinitely narrow but when you use $H^1$ you basically "follow" the line so the area becomes its length?

Comment: Does $\lambda^d(E) =[\lambda^1([0, 1])]^{d-1}$ have a name? Or could you point me to a resource?

Comment: That is correct. :)

Comment: Wait so this means that $H^{d-1} \ll \lambda^d$ is not true!

Comment: How about the opposite though? Is there a relationship similar (not necessarily identical) to $\lambda^{d-1} \ll H^{d-1}$ or $\lambda^{d-1} \ll H^d$ ?

Comment: It is true that $\lambda^{d}\ll H^{d-1}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. However, this does not mean that $\lambda^{d}$ has a Radno-Nikodym derivative w.r.t. $H^{d-1}$ because $H^{d-1}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is not $\sigma$-additive (and hence the Radon-Nikodym theorem does not apply). On the other hand, we have $\lambda^{d-1} = c H^{d-1}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ for a suitable constant $c\in(0,\infty)$. (Although it would be natural to define $H^{d-1}$ so that this normalizing constant is exactly $1$,  the actual value of $c$ may depend on the particular definition of $H^{d-1}$ used in the context.)

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you so much. Does the expression $\lambda^d \ll H^{d-1}$ essentially mean (following your example) that if we have a line segment $L = [0,1]\times\{0\}\times\{0\}$ then this has $0$ volume in $\mathbb{R}^3$, zero area in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but unit length in $\mathbb{R}$, that is $\lambda^3(L) = 0$, $H^2(L) = 0$ and $H^1(L)=1$?

Comment: @SangchulLee also, does this mean that $H^{d-1}$ is never going to be $\sigma$-additive? If that's the case, does this mean that even if I were to find some other $\nu\ll H^{d-1}$ then we wouldn't have the Radon-Nykodym derivative?

Comment: @SangchulLee Finally, do you mean $\sigma$-additive or $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that $H^{d-1}$ is not $\sigma$-finite.